# How to provide a "default slot_list" in openmpi rankfile?

Tags: openmpi

I am running my programs using OpenMPI's [`mpiexec`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man1/mpiexec.1.php) command.  I wish to allocate the processes in the following manner:

- The rank with id `0` should occupy more than one cores (let's make it 4, for example);
- All other ranks should each occupy one core.

This is because the rank `0` does something special that no other ranks do, and it needs more than one core for it.

I'm trying to find some combination of command-line arguments and ["rankfile"](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning#using-paffinity-v1.3) specifications for fulfilling this purpose.  So far, I've tried a rankfile (named `openmpi-rankfile`) with one line like this:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0:0-3
```

However, when I run the program with command line like

```
mpiexec -n 20 -rankfile openmpi-rankfile path/to/executable -some arguments
```

openmpi complains:

> A rank is missing its location specification:
>
> Rank:        1
>   Rank file:   `openmpi-rankfile`
>
> All processes must have their location specified in the rank file. Either
>   add an entry to the file, **or provide a default slot_list to use for
>   any unspecified ranks**.

(Emphasis mine)

So my question is:  How do I "provide a *default* slot_list to use for any unspecified ranks"?

BTW I could probably have resorted to generating a rankfile which explicitly specifies the slots for each rank, but this sounds wasteful.  I'm interested in this "default slot_list" setting.